# Right Acute and Obtuse Triangles in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, math, trigonometry

I am trying to write a code for a triangle program which prompts user to enter any 6 coordinates and the program determines whether the triangle is acute, obtuse, right, scalene, equilateral, isosceles. It also finds the area and perimeter of program and determines whether the 6 coordinates form a triangle at all. I was successful in doing most part of the program but I am having difficulties in writing code for determining if the triangle is acute, right and obtuse. Here is my code for right, acute and obtuse triangles. My main problem is that when the program runs, no matter what coordinates I put, it always gives me the answer as "Acute". I have tried coordinates for right and obtuse yet I still get acute. I think I have a problem in logic.

```
def right(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    # Using Pythagoras theorem
    sideAB = sideLength(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    sideBC = sideLength(x2, y2, x3, y3)
    sideAC = sideLength(x3, y3, x1, y1)
    largest = max(sideAB, sideBC, sideAC)
    var1 = min(sideAB, sideBC, sideAC)
    if sideAB != largest and sideAB != var1:
        var2 = sideAB
    elif sideBC != largest and sideBC != var1:
        var2 = sideBC
    else:
        var2 = sideAC

    if (largest) ** 2 == ((var1 ** 2 + (var2) ** 2)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

For obtuse

```
def obtuse(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    sideAB = sideLength(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    sideBC = sideLength(x2, y2, x3, y3)
    sideAC = sideLength(x3, y3, x1, y1)
    largest = max(sideAB, sideBC, sideAC)
    var1 = min(sideAB, sideBC, sideAC)
    if sideAB != largest and sideAB != var1:
        var2 = sideAB
    elif sideBC != largest and sideBC != var1:
        var2 = sideBC
    else:
        var2 = sideAC
    if (largest) ** 2 > ((var1) ** 2 + (var2) ** 2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And for Acute

```
def acute(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    sideAB = sideLength(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    sideBC = sideLength(x2, y2, x3, y3)
    sideAC = sideLength(x3, y3, x1, y1)
    largest = max(sideAB, sideBC, sideAC)
    var1 = min(sideAB, sideBC, sideAC)
    if sideAB != largest and sideAB != var1:
        var2 = sideAB
    elif sideBC != largest and sideBC != var1:
        var2 = sideBC
    else:
        var2 = sideAC
    if (largest) ** 2 < ((var1) ** 2 + (var2) ** 2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Can someone please correct/improvise my code so that it determines the measures for being right, acute and obtuse? Thanks!

Here is my sideLength function

```
def sideLength(x1, y1, x2, y2):

    length = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    return length


# Using the min function to find out the shortest side.

def findAllSides(vertices):

    x1 = vertices[0][0]
    y1 = vertices[0][1]
    x2 = vertices[1][0]
    y2 = vertices[1][1]
    x3 = vertices[2][0]
    y3 = vertices[2][1]

    sideAB = sideLength(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    sideBC = sideLength(x2, y2, x3, y3)
    sideAC = sideLength(x3, y3, x1, y1)
    lst=[sideAB, sideAC, sideBC]

    return lst
```

Comment: ...what exactly does *"I am having difficulties"* mean? Give a [mcve], this isn't a tutorial service.

Comment: I posted it exactly 7 seconds ago. Please read before leaving negative downvotes.

Comment: 1. That's obviously inaccurate, my comment was posted ~2 minutes after the question. 2. It doesn't take long to scan a post for an on-topic question and come up empty. **This isn't a tutorial service**, read [ask] - cut the code down to a [mcve] with inputs and expected and actual outputs.

Comment: Please move on if you have nothing constructive to say. I'm sure using profanity is also against the guidelines of this website.

Comment: Fair point, edited. Please move on if you have nothing on-topic to ask, and maybe avail yourself of those very guidelines?

Comment: I hope my answer should be enough to understand; and also short enough for not being upset about a not-quite-fitting question

Comment: So, trying to find a middle ground between yelling about MCVE's, and actually taking good advice - @JakeMeyer - can you provide two specific sets of coordinates, one you beleive to be `right` and one you believe to be `obtuse`, that are showing up as `acute` for you?

Comment: Sure Obtuse: 0 0 5 1 10 0
Right: 0 4 0 0 4 0

Comment: @dwanderson well, thanks for the support.

Comment: @JakeMeyer found the error, it was indead logic :o
Check my edited answer, and test if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your code more concise you can do the main calculation in a single function:

(Dont repeat yourself!)

```
def typeObtuseRightAcute(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    #no idea if this is a good value but works for example
    #and should be low enough to give right answers for all but crazy close triangles
    epsilon=10**-8
    # Using Pythagoras theorem
    sideAB = sideLength(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    sideBC = sideLength(x2, y2, x3, y3)
    sideAC = sideLength(x3, y3, x1, y1)

    #use this instead
    [var1,var2,largest] = sorted([sideAB, sideBC, sideAC])



    if abs((largest) ** 2-((var1 ** 2 + (var2) ** 2)))<epsilon:
        return "right"
    elif (largest) ** 2 > ((var1 ** 2 + (var2) ** 2)):
        return "obtuse"
    else:
        return "acute"

def acute(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    return typeObtuseRightAcute(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)=="acute"

def right(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    return typeObtuseRightAcute(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)=="right"

def obtuse(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    return typeObtuseRightAcute(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)=="obtuse"
```

But I believe this question should be asked in Code Review instead of here, since your code works and you just want to know how to write it better (I believe?)

EDIT

Found the error:

```
    if sideAB != largest and sideAB != var1:
        var2 = sideAB
    elif sideBC != largest and sideBC != var1:
        var2 = sideBC
    else:
        var2 = sideAC
```

this part of the code leads to errors if the two shorter sides have the same length, and AC is the longest one.

The following happens:

Let us say `AC` is largest and `AB = var1`

The first `if` fails, since `AB==var1`

The second `if` fails, since `BC` and `AB` have the same length

-> `var2` is assigned `AC` and you have a wrong side!

Changed my code to be correct. Either use that one or change it in every function. (Not sure if sorted() works the same way in python 3... try it out^^)

EDIT2:
Changed equality check, because floating point numbers are a pain -_-

Comment: I believe the problem is in the logic of the program and not how it is written as I keep getting the answer as "Acute" even when I put in the coordinates for right or obtuse.

Comment: I tried this program with my own `sideLength` function, with coordonates `(0,0) (3,0) (0,4)` and got `right` as answer. Maybe sideLength is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I posted my sideLength function in the question now. Can you please check it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh just so that its clear, the format of entry is like this `Jake 0 0 3 0 0 4`

Comment: Minor note - this will get even cleaner/better once Python has `enumeration`s, rather than being `string-ly typed`, but since that's how Python does it, that's all you can do for now :)

Comment: Same as many, I see no reason why it shouldn't work o.0
By the way, we do this in one function instead of three to isolate errors much easier.

Comment: @dwanderson could you expand on that? Python has `enumerate` and `Enum` - what precisely are you talking about?

Comment: @dwanderson I am still working in python 2.7 so I will never get enums ;)

Comment: @JakeMeyer Well your funtion works fine if I run it, probably an error in the logic elsewhere...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Python3.5 has Enum, but nothing before, and lots of systems are still on Python2.7 - it was more of an offhand comment pointing out the ugliness of doing a string comparison on something that has no reasons to involve strings (and again, not  directed at JeD; that's the msot reasonable Pythonic way to do it in 2.7)

Comment: @dwanderson ah, I see - you're aware of the [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) to 2.4 and up? Also, there was never anything stopping a user from simply creating their own *"constants"* `ACUTE = 1`, etc..

Comment: @jonrsharpe backported? Oh well, time to learn some Syntax *flies away*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wasn't aware of the backport for `Enum`. I'd agree, in these cases I'd opt for "constants" rather than strings, forgot about that.

Comment: @JeD, these coordinates (0, 4) , (0, 0) , (4, 0)are still being reported as Obtuse instead of right. Is there a way to make changes logically in my code? We are instructed to have separate functions for each triangle classification.

Comment: @JakeMeyer damn, I'm sorry. Now we have a new problem, floating point numbers. Whats happening is that pythong gets small errors in calculating the side lengths, and therefore returns the wrong value... Let me think about it.

Comment: Is using Epsilon any help?

Comment: @JakeMeyer yeah, good idea, just have to figure out a good value for epsilon. I'm editing my answer ( again)

Comment: @JakeMeyer no prob. I hope it finally works ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I found out that my scalene, isosceles and equilateral logic is flawed as well. I guess I will need to formulate that properly in another question :( I am thankful for all the helpful people like you on Stackoverflow

Comment: Can you please check on this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094916/scalene-equilateral-and-isosceles-triangles-in-python

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question but rather pure calculation. I'll try to briefly 'improvise' without concrete code.

First, why do you use three functions, make them one, as follows:

choose the longest side, as you have already, and take the dot product of the two others (this means you need the two sides as vectors and either use `np.dot` or calculate by hand: `x1*x2 + y1*y2`). Then the sign (`np.sign` or a self-written `if`-clause) of this dot product determines, whether the angle is 90° (if 0), or greater (if `dot` is negative) or less (if positive).

That's all, you can then make your function output one of these three options. Using three distinct functions is not good, since their outcome is not independent: you always get exactly one of the three choices.

Comment: I could post my entire program if you would like.

Comment: @JakeMeyer again, we want a [mcve], not your *"entire program"*.

Comment: @JakeMeyer firstly, you can't claim *"again"* when you haven't said it once. You said *"Please move on if you have nothing constructive to say"* - what precisely is not constructive about suggesting how you could improve the question? Secondly, if you don't want people to comment, go somewhere that doesn't actively encourage community participation.

Comment: I would agree, that the question does not look as if it was easy to scan and answer. But it took me two minutes (because I did not really read the code, since it works) two see what the point is and answer. So it's good enough, apparently...

Comment: He is not trolling, he is trying to tell you how to write better questions.

Comment: as an impartial spectator I would judge, that "never provide your opinion, when you are not asked to" is the rudest part of the conversation. It's fascinating, how fast humans are able to forget the original topic.